# How to solve "ant design base css" and "tailwindcss base css" alignments problem? How to avoid antd modifying global styles?

Tags: css, webpack, less, tailwind-css, ant-design-pro

I prefer create project style and components style with tailwind css framework. I want to use a few ant design component. Tailwindcss and ant.design have problems together. Ant design alignment loses when we import `@import 'tailwindcss/base'` to the project and when we delete it ant design alignment will work fine. ant design modify global styles and [according of document I try to prevent this](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#How-to-avoid-modifying-global-styles) but not work this method for me!
My babel.config.js:

```js
['import', { libraryName: 'antd', libraryDirectory: 'es', style: true }],
```

I add this plugin to my webpack config:

```js
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
  /node_modules\/antd\/lib\/style\/index\.less/,
  path.resolve(__dirname, './src/antd.less'),
),
```

and `antd.less` file:

```
#antd {
  @import '~antd/es/style/core/index.less';
  @import '~antd/es/style/themes/default.less';
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend overriding some of [Tailwind's base styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight/) that are causing problems with Ant Design. For me, Ant Design icons did not have the correct vertical alignment when including Tailwind, so I replaced their default svg style in my global css file.

```
@tailwind base;

/* Override base SVG style to work with Ant Design */
svg {
  vertical-align: initial;
}
```

Comment: @DaniloKörber Hi! do you mange to integrate those two? I'm having problem on some ant components like Skeleton and the tooltip

Answer (score 13):

TailwindCSS [applies certain base styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight/) to smoothen the cross-browser experience.

Since you are also using Ant Design, which applies some base styles of its own, setting `preflight` to false in your tailwind config should work:

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    module.exports = {
          content: [
            "./src/**/*. 
        {js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
           ],
          theme: {
             extend: {},
          },
          plugins: [
             // ...
          ],
          corePlugins: {
               preflight: false 
                 // <== disable 
           this!
           },
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).