# how to remove tailwind prefights for specific pages

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

There is an option in `tailwind.config.cjs` to turn off preflights. But i don't want to turn them off for the whole project. i need them to be enabled for some specific pages. Is there a way to do that.

Turn off preflights:

```js
// tailwind.config.cjs
...
corePlugins: {
  preflight: false,
},
...
```

Comment: Do you have one CSS file for every page or you may specify which CSS file to use on which page?

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka no i dont have one css file for every page

Comment: Remove `preflight: false` and import `@tailwind base` only on the pages your need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question on [tailwindcss discussions](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/10332#discussioncomment-4698289) and found my answer.

This is the solution just add this plugin to your plugins and disable the preflight option.:

```js
// with class "tailwind-preflight" we can now add preflight only to components we want
// to prevent conflicts between ant design and tailwind

const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const postcss = require("postcss");

module.exports = plugin(function ({ addBase }) {
  const preflightStyles = postcss.parse(
    fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./preflight.css"), "utf8"),
  );

  // Scope the selectors to specific components
  preflightStyles.walkRules((rule) => {
    rule.selector = ".tailwind-preflight " + rule.selector;
  });

  addBase(preflightStyles.nodes);
});
```

Tailwind docs about plugins:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins

Comment: Can you share me how to do this?

Comment: Hi @Samyar, I'm facing the same problem but cannot piece together your answer. Can you please show how to do this with examples on how to add preflight to certain components?

Comment: @Ryan refer to the mentioned GitHub page and the tailwind docs about plugins